# how to access folder variables across pipeline stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create multiple pipeline jobs under a folder. Under this folder I have created some folder properties. I am having a hard time to use this folder properties across multiple stages in a job.

plugin used : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Folder+Properties+Plugin

```
def region
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Assign values to global properties') {
            steps {
                withFolderProperties{
                    region = "${env.appRegion}"
                }       
            }
        }
        stage('Print') {
            steps {
                print(region)      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Expected a step @ line 8, column 21.
                       region = "${env.appRegion}"
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`region = "${env.appRegion}"` is not pipeline reserved name of step or directive.  It's groovy statement. You should put them inside `script` step.  If you used **Scripted Pipeline** you can put any kinds of groovy statement in anywhere. But for **Declarative Pipeline** any groovy statement should wrapped in `script` step.

```
steps {
    script {
        withFolderProperties{
            region = "${env.appRegion}"
        }
    }
}

steps {
    withFolderProperties{
        script {
            region = "${env.appRegion}"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which one code block above is work, but you can give a try.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!groovy

def CI_NAMESPACE = ""
withFolderProperties{
    CI_NAMESPACE = "${env.CI_NAMESPACE}"
}

println "CI_NAMESPACE = ${CI_NAMESPACE}"

if (CI_NAMESPACE == '' || CI_NAMESPACE == null || CI_NAMESPACE == 'null') {
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
    error('Not defined CI_NAMESPACE in Folder properies plugin!')
}

pipeline {
    environment {
        CI_NAMESPACE = "${CI_NAMESPACE}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "CI_NAMESPACE: ${env.CI_NAMESPACE}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].