# Jenkinsfile Folder variables missing from env

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use folder variables in a jenkinsfile
I tried [how to access folder variables across pipeline stages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856401/how-to-access-folder-variables-across-pipeline-stages) but I don't get it working.

On the Experimental Folder I added 2 properties

- CCEBUILD_TOOLS_BRANCH
- TEST

`sh 'printenv'`  displays my Folder variables, but they do not show up with `env.getEnvironment()`

Why is this not working ?

```
def printParams() {
    env.getEnvironment().each { name, value -> println "In printParams Name: $name -> Value $value" }
}

node() {
    withFolderProperties{

        stage('Info') {
            sh 'printenv'
            println env.getEnvironment().collect({environmentVariable ->  "${environmentVariable.key} = ${environmentVariable.value}"}).join("\n")
            
            /* printParams()*/
        }
    }
    
}
```

#### printenv output

```
_=/bin/printenv
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#25
BUILD_ID=25
BUILD_NUMBER=25
BUILD_TAG=*****-*******-********-*****
BUILD_URL=https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/
CCEBUILD_TOOLS_BRANCH=develop_staging
EXECUTOR_NUMBER=4
HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
HUDSON_COOKIE=*****-*******-********-*****
HUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=************
HUDSON_URL=https://hostname/
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=*****-*******-********-*****
JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=durable-*****-*******-********-*****
JENKINS_URL=https://hostname/
JOB_BASE_NAME=Linux info
JOB_DISPLAY_URL=https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/display/redirect
JOB_NAME=Experimental/Linux info
JOB_URL=https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=jenkins
NODE_LABELS=developmenthost devlinux linux master releasehost rtbhost
NODE_NAME=master
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
PWD=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Experimental/jobs/Linux info/workspace
RUN_ARTIFACTS_DISPLAY_URL=https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/display/redirect?page=artifacts
RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL=https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/display/redirect?page=changes
RUN_DISPLAY_URL=https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/display/redirect
RUN_TESTS_DISPLAY_URL=https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/display/redirect?page=tests
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=4
STAGE_NAME=Info
TEST=Ok
USER=jenkins
WORKSPACE=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Experimental/jobs/Linux info/workspace
```

#### env output

```
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME = #25
BUILD_ID = 25
BUILD_NUMBER = 25
BUILD_TAG =*****-*******-********-*****
BUILD_URL = https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/
CLASSPATH = 
HUDSON_HOME = /var/lib/jenkins
HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = ************
HUDSON_URL = https://hostname/
JENKINS_HOME = /var/lib/jenkins
JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE = ************
JENKINS_URL = https://hostname/
JOB_BASE_NAME = Linux info
JOB_DISPLAY_URL = https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/display/redirect
JOB_NAME = Experimental/Linux info
JOB_URL = https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/
RUN_ARTIFACTS_DISPLAY_URL = https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/display/redirect?page=artifacts
RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL = https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/display/redirect?page=changes
RUN_DISPLAY_URL = https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/display/redirect
RUN_TESTS_DISPLAY_URL = https://hostname/job/Experimental/job/Linux%20info/25/display/redirect?page=tests
```

Comment: The `sh` step method with `printenv` argument will display the environment for the shell interpreter. The `env` object stores the environment for the pipeline. That is why they are different. Why they are different becuase of the folder variables I do not know. It will be only be important if you need to access the variables from the pipeline environment.

Comment: I'm trying to add build parameters to a Jenkins folder. Those parameters are used in the jenkinsfile and should have the same value across all jobs in the folder. Folder properties seemed the right way to do this. I don't understand the use of Folder properties if you can't easily read them.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a loader class to load properties by iterating through parent folders.

[com.mig82.folders.properties.PropertiesLoader](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/plugin/folder-properties/com/mig82/folders/properties/PropertiesLoader.html)

I encountered an issue where I was unable to edit folder properties within the withFolderProperties block.

To work around this, I iterated over the folder properties using the loader and then stored them in the standard environment variables.

Here is my code sample

```
import com.mig82.folders.properties.PropertiesLoader

node ("my-label") {
    stage ("Folder Envs") {
        PropertiesLoader.loadFolderProperties(currentBuild.getRawBuild().project).each { name, value ->
            if (value.length() == 0) {
                echo "Skipping ${name} = ${value} (empty)"
                return
            }
            
            env."${name}" = value
            echo "Setting ${name} = ${value}"
        }
    }
}
```